# Copy data from one Postgres database to another

Tags: postgresql

I have two databases

`db_dumped` -- contains data in **main_facebookparserresult** table

`lk_potok_4` -- contains empty table **main_facebookparserresult**

I want to copy data from db_dumped to lk_potok_4.

**My actions:** (no errors)

```
pg_dump -U postgres  -h localhost  -t main_facebookparserresult  db_dumped  | psql lk_potok_4 -U postgres  -h localhost
```

I see the following error

```
SET
...
 set_config 
------------
 
(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "main_facebookparserresult_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY main_facebookparserresult, line 1
 setval 
--------
  34367
(1 row)

ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "main_facebookparserresult" are not allowed
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_account_type_id_825ffe90" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_country_id_42b851f9" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_current_city_id_4ea3868d" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_edu_type_id_87f43c00" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_employment_status_id_808992ba" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_employment_type_id_911556be" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_family_status_id_ee099277" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_gender_id_2a17909b" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_home_city_id_a8b99ee3" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_relation_id_94f96514" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_social_network_type_id_cd0395b0" already exists
ERROR:  relation "main_facebookparserresult_university_id_0890ffdd" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_account_type_id_825ffe90_fk_main_acco" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_country_id_42b851f9_fk_main_coun" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_current_city_id_4ea3868d_fk_main_city" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_edu_type_id_87f43c00_fk_main_edut" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_employment_status_id_808992ba_fk_main_empl" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_employment_type_id_911556be_fk_main_empl" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_family_status_id_ee099277_fk_main_fami" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_relation_id_94f96514_fk_main_rela" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_social_network_type__cd0395b0_fk_main_soci" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserr_university_id_0890ffdd_fk_main_univ" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserresult_gender_id_2a17909b_fk_main_gender_id" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "main_facebookparserresult_home_city_id_a8b99ee3_fk_main_city_id" for relation "main_facebookparserresult" already exists
```

What I did wrong? How can i understand what is the error?

Comment: 1) db_dumped - is a database (not dump)

Comment: 2) I don't understand what should i fix in this part? 
 | psql lk_potok_4 looks fine

Comment: My mistake I did not read the question correctly. Also I was looking at the wrong part of your commands. `sudo -u postgres psql` is going to drop you into the `psql` program. You cannot run the `pg_dump ...` from there. Just run the `pg_dump ..` in your user shell, you don't need to switch to the `postgres` user.

Comment: Thank you, but I have the next level error. Could you please take a look?

Comment: You need update your question with more detailed information about what you are trying to achieve? The errors you are seeing are because the table already exists in the receiving database. So one of the things you need to determine is whether you want to recreate the table from scratch or just move the data.

Answer (score 3):

Your dump contains both the data and the schema for `main_facebookparserresult`. It's trying to create the table `main_facebookparserresult`, but it already exists.

You should either drop the table OR dump just the data with `--data-only`. Since the table is empty I would suggest dropping the table; this ensures the table is created correctly.

Comment: Thank you but, I ave another error. Please, take a look at UPDATE block

Comment: @Alex It is better if you ask a new question for each new problem. Editing the question makes the comments and answers make no sense. Asking a new question will get more visibility. Please link the new question @ me and I'll have a look.